# Color code lang.eng file in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm making my own texture pack in Minecraft and was playing around with the lang.eng file to change the text color for items/menu and so on.

I came up with a problem I am having: let’s say I want to change color for the render distance setting for chunks, I can change the title names color but the number for the chunks I select doesn't change.

How do I change the color of %s tho I assume that is the string after the name for the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

The symbol for changing colors is: §

For a list of the compatible color codes, check out this website: https://www.digminecraft.com/lists/color_list_pc.php

For example, in the lang file, you would have something to the effect of:

```
"subtitles.entity.creeper.primed": "§c§lCreeper hisses"
```

In this example, "l" makes it bold, and "c" makes it red.

Comment: Please stop editing the post to include commentary or clarification from others.  Voting is anonymous, and asking why something was downvoted on a post itself either through comments or edits is usually not received well and are invalid edits.  You can ask more broadly _why_ your post received downvotes/poor reception on our [Meta site](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you wish.  If you want to request clarification on the _question_, you can tag the original poster in a comment.